Adding values from a table to selected data
I have 2 tables. One is general and the other is more detailed. I need to use data from both tables. Right now I am using a temporary help table to do some things and then publish the data. However I don't like this solution and I am trying to find a way to do it without the temporary table.
Here is the code so far:
DELETE FROM TableHelp
 INSERT INTO TableHelp (col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SELECT  TableGeneral.col1, TableGeneral.col2, TableGeneral.col3, TableGeneral.col4           
    FROM    TableGeneral
 WHERE     (col2 >= @param1)
 AND   col3 LIKE (@param2)
 Order By CAST( TableGeneral.col1 AS BIGINT)

 UPDATE TableHelp
SET TableHelp.col5 = TableDetail.col10
FROM TableHelp
INNER JOIN TableDetail ON TableHelp.col1 = TableDetail.col1
WHERE TableDetail.col7 LIKE 'condition';

Select * From TableHelp

This seems like it is doing what I need (not completely sure, I have a lot of data, so I didn't check everything).
Is there a way to handle this without using the help table?
Firstly I want to filter data from the general table according to the WHERE clause and @parameters. After that I want to add to the filtered data values from another table according to some condition.
Just to be sure I will write what exactly I want:
TableGeneral



col1
col2
col3
col4




1
aaa
aaa
aaa


2
bbb
bbb
bbb


3
ccc
ccc
ccc


4
ddd
ddd
ddd



TableDetaill



col1
col2
col3
col4
...
col7
col10




1
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value1


1
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
condition
value2


1
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value3


2
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
condition
value4


2
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value5


2
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value6


3
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value7


3
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value8


3
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value9


4
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value10


4
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
value11


4
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
condition
value12



Output should be



col1
col2
col3
col4
col5




1
aaa
aaa
aaa
value2


2
bbb
bbb
bbb
value4


3
ccc
ccc
ccc
0


4
ddd
ddd
ddd
value12



If I have to use the help db, than okay. However, I was curious if I can do it with some combination of conditions and functions without the table.

SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything. (I've assumed SQL Server for now, as it's the most likely candidate.)

Yes exactly. Sorry for that

I believe a LEFT OUTER JOIN between general and detail will work:
SELECT tg.col1, tg.col2, tg.col3, tg.col4, td.col10 as col5
FROM TableGeneral tg 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableDetail td 
    ON td.col1 = td.col1 
    AND td.col2 like 'condition'
WHERE tg.col2 >= @param1
  AND tg.col3 LIKE @param2
ORDER BY CAST(tg.col1 AS BIGINT)

Since you are using an UPDATE for the second step, a LEFT OUTER JOIN feels appropriate in case there is tg.col1 value that isn't in td.col1. Also the condition to limit TableDetail is moved up into the join criteria for td so that the filter is applied before the join occurs.
